# Best way to wait for multiple getObjectsAtPath to finish

Tags: objective-c, rest, ios6, restkit

When my user logs in, I have multiple:

```
 [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] 
     getObjectsAtPath:path
     parameters:nil<br/> success:
         ^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
```

Now, I want to wait for all of them to finish to show the next page. I thought about putting them one inside another and return from the block until it reaches the last one, but this seems to kill the purpose of having async calls.

I thought about having a dictionary where I set the keys to YES and NO once a specific part is done, and wait for all the keys to be set to YES, but this seems prone to locks/concurrency problems.

So, any ideas to do this?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary route should work and shouldn't have any threading issues as the success & error callbacks are all run on the main thread.

Alternatively you could use a simple counter if you don't care about which ones are finished and which aren't.

Alternatively you could use the `operationQueue` of the `RKObjectManager` and check in each success block if any tasks are still to be completed (though you need to consider the effectiveness if you are using the `sharedManager` and how many other things may be on the queue at the same time).